# error with content search webpart

Tags: content-search-web-part

I have a content search webpart added in my homepage and displaying the result.
I have added new CEWP in same homepage and link it with JS file which has certain functionality. but this result in disappearing of result of search webpart and as soon I de-link js file in CEWP result again get displayed. JS functionality if working fine in other test page or in same page after result from searach webpart get disappeared. Please help me know why search result is not displaying after adding CEWP and linking with JS file. Thanks

Comment: Can you try your JS code in text file with <script> tag in it and give it a try?

Comment: yes doing same jscript is in txt file and linked that to CEWP

Comment: something in your js code that is breaking the page may be

Answer (score 0):

this probably happens when your code and your search result web part code having the same variable name or function name. so kindly check . or you can provide a shareable location where we can check your js file.